# How to type classes when passing them as a prop in material ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-proptypes

I find myself writing a few generic components in material ui, where the styling is actually defined in a parent or grandparent component.  For example:

```js
const GenericDescendant = (props: DescendantProps) => {
  const { classesFromAncestor, ...other } = props
  return <Button className={classesFromAncestor} {...props}>Text here</Button>
}
```

Where from the Ancestor, I create a `useStyles` and `classes` object and pass it down:

```js
const useDescendantStyles = makeStyles({
  selector: { 
    border: '1px solid green',
    // more customized styles
  }
})

const Ancestor = () => {
  const descendantClasses = useDescendantStyles()
  return <GenericDescendant classesFromAncestor={descendantClasses} />
}
```

Or another way, I can use `withStyles` to wrap a component used in the descendant:

```js
const GenericDescendant = (props: DescendantProps) => {
  const { tooltipClassesFromAncestor, buttonClassesFromAncestor, ...other } = props
  const CustmoizedTooltip = withStyles(tooltipClassesFromAncestor)(Tooltip);
  const CustomButton = withStyles(buttonClassesFromAncestor)(Button)
  return (
    <CustmoizedTooltip>
      <CustomButton>Text here</CustomButton>
    </CustmoizedTooltip>
  )
}
```

In this case, I wouldn't call `useStyles` in the Ancestor, I would just pass the object like this:

```js
const Ancestor = () => {
  return <GenericDescendant classesFromAncestor={{
    selector: { 
      border: '1px solid green',
      // more customized styles
    }
  }} />
}
```

I don't want to just wrap the whole `GenericDescendant` in a `withStyles`, because then I can't target which component is taking the custom styles being passed from the ancestor.

The cases are slightly different, but I can go either route to allow customization of a generic descendant from the ancestor.  However, when passing the customized styles as a prop, I don't know how to properly type the `classesFromAncestor` prop in `DescendantProps`.  It could really take any form, and that form won't be known until runtime.  I don't want to type it as `any`.  What's the best way to define the type of classes that are passed as a prop?

Comment: The version with `<CustmoizedTooltip>` etc is going to have issues with losing focus on re-render because you don't want to create a component within the body of another component.  That causes an unmount and remount of a new instance of the created component on every render of the parent.  I'm wondering if it makes sense to do this with mapping of children via `React.cloneElement`.

Comment: If `classesFromAncestor` comes from a `makeStyles` then it is a type that is exported from `@material-ui/styles` as `ClassNameMap`.  It is essentially `Record<string, string>`.  But in your last example you are passing the arguments used to create the classes rather than the class map itself.  That's basically `Record<string, CSSProperties>`, but material-ui supports a lot of other options and formats.

Comment: This is working!  I have a few instances of each method, and applying `ClassNameMap` when passing the actual `classes` object down as a prop works, and `Record<string, CSSProperties>` works when spreading it into a `withStyles` call.  I agree, I hate having a component rendered inside of another component, and it *is* causing focus issues.  I could just use the `className={classesFromAncestor}` method instead of `withStyles` , they seem to be functionally the same.  If you write this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been playing with this and there are many possible setups.  You can style a material-ui component by passing a single `string` `className` and you can also pass an object of `classes` which correspond to the different selectors available for that component.  The primary selector for most (but not all) Material components is `root`. A `Button` accepts classes `root`, `label`, `text`, and [many others](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css).

When you call `makeStyles` what you create is an `object` where the keys are the selectors, basically the same keys as your input, and the values are the `string` class names for the generated classes.  You can import this type as `ClassNameMap` from `@material-ui/styles`.  It is essentially `Record<string, string>`, but with an optional generic that lets you restrict the keys.

```
export type ClassNameMap<ClassKey extends string = string> = Record<ClassKey, string>;
```

The first argument that you pass to `makeStyles` or `withStyles` is your keyed object of styles properties.  It can be simplified to `Record<string, CSSProperties>` or you can import the complex type from material-ui which includes support for functions, etc.  The type `Styles<Theme, Props, ClassKey>` takes three optional generics where `Theme` is the type of your theme, `Props` is the component's own props, and `ClassKey` is again the supported selectors.  `Theme` and `Props` are mainly included so that you can map your styles as a function of `theme` or `props`.

If we want to provide styles to multiple components at once, a simplistic way would be to create a styles object with one key for each component.  You can call them anything.  We then pass each of those styles as the `className` to the component.

```
const MyStyled = withStyles({
  button: {
    border: "green",
    background: "yellow"
  },
  checkbox: {
    background: "red"
  }
})(({ classes }: { classes: ClassNameMap }) => (
  <Button className={classes.button}>
    <Checkbox className={classes.checkbox} />
    Text Here
  </Button>
));
```

That setup allows for any number of components at any level of nesting.

I played a bit with making a higher-order component that can wrap your outer component.  You can use this as a starting point and tweak it to your needs.

```
const withAncestralStyles = <Props extends { className?: string } = {}>(
  Component: ComponentType<Props>,
  style: Styles<DefaultTheme, Omit<Props, "children">, string>
) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(style);

  return (
    props: Omit<Props, "children"> & {
      children?: (styles: ClassNameMap) => ReactNode;
    }
  ) => {
    console.log(props);
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    const { children, className, ...rest } = props;
    return (
      <Component {...rest as Props} className={`${className} ${classes.root}`}>
        {children ? children(classes) : undefined}
      </Component>
    );
  };
};
```

Basically, the class `classes.root` will get automatically applied to the `className` of the parent while all styles are passed to the child as props (but not applied).  I had trouble making `React.cloneElement` work, so I am requiring that the `children` of the component be a `function` which receives the `classes` object.

```
const StyledButton = withAncestralStyles(Button, {
  root: {
    border: "green",
    background: "yellow"
  },
  checkbox: {
    background: "red"
  }
});

const MyComponent = () => (
  <StyledButton onClick={() => alert('clicked')}>
    {(classes) => <><Checkbox className={classes.checkbox}/>Some Text</>}
  </StyledButton>
);
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-65996439-9x293?file=/src/App.tsx)

This approach did not work properly with your `Tooltip` example because `Tooltip` is one of the components that does not have a `root` selector and needs to be styled differently to target the popover.

Comment: This answer is above and beyond. Thank you!

Comment: This answer has been working great, but looking more closely at the tooltip situation, I'm running into exactly the problem you described.  So instead of passing `tooltipClassesFromAncestor` as a simple object to be spread into a `withStyles` call, I am trying to use the `const descendantClasses = useDescendantStyles()` method, passing `descendantClasses` as a prop, and using `className={classes.descendantClasses}` on a Tooltip component.  But the styled passed seem to be styling the tooltip's child, not the tooltip itself.  Any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: Based on this: https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#css I think what you want is to be passing a classes object and applying the styles to the popper property.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, if you are passing the result of `makeStyles` then it is `Record<string, string>`. However, if you're passing CSS-in-JS objects then you could do something like this:

```
import { ListItemClassKey } from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';

type RecursiveCSSProperties = {
  [key: string]: React.CSSProperties | RecursiveCSSProperties;
}

type MuiComponentClasses<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]?: React.CSSProperties | RecursiveCSSProperties;
};

const myListItemClasses: MuiComponentClasses<ListItemClassKey> = {
  secondaryAction: {},
  divider: {
    margin: 56,
    top: 0,
    "& .myClass": {
      background: 'red',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  }
}
```

The output structure should demonstrate why recursion over `React.CSSProperties` is necessary to get all the possible nests of CSS that can be made with CSS-in-JSS libraries. The second type `MuiComponentClasses` is optional but will allow you to pull in a key list from the relevant component so that you are only targeting the correct keys in the top level of the class object.

Comment: I went for a jog to clear my head and was trying to think of how to write `RecursiveCSSProperties`...and then I came back and you had written it. Thank you